# Proving irrationality of $x$ constructed by Cantor's diagonal argument

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers

Suppose we don't know the set of all rational numbers is countable. Also assume $x$ is constructed by Cantor's diagonal argument for the set $(0,1)\cap \mathbb{Q}$. Then how to show that the decimal representation of $x$ is not periodic?

Comment: If you do not know the set of all rational numbers in $(0,1)$ is countable, you cannot begin the Cantor diagonal argument for $(0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. That is because the argument starts by listing all elements of $(0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: It seems like you want to use the Cantor method to show that the set is countable by showing that the list does NOT given another rational number. I am not sure whether this works.